# install package B, if package A fails

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2, setup.py

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer.

I created a package that is basically just a wrapper around psycopg2 that makes it easier to do some of the things that i'll need to do. I published it with pip and everything was fine on my local machine. When trying to install into a RHEL EC-2, I got an error message--

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nc1i9qio/psycopg2/
```

It will work if I install psycopg2-binary instead of psycopg2. This is fine (psycopg2-binary imports as psycopg2) except, it makes my package un-installable. Any ideas on how to fix? Would prefer adding the fix to the package and not monkey-patching the install, but either will suffice for now.